# 2L water container graph

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

for math homework we need to create a sort of vase in a graph in which I am using desmos, and we have to use a Linear, Polynomial and Exponential equations. also the design "must contain" a full set of functions or equations (hybrid functions) that would allow the reader to reproduce the design themselves.

I have no idea where to start, besides knowing it needs to be 2000 units with calculus, or have a marker where it hits the 2L point.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you representing the volume of the container? is the two liters the volume when rotated around an axis or just the area of the 2d-plot?

Comment: err you make it in 2d but it turns out to be 3d for rotation